# Java Spark on a Heroku server not binding to the port and crashing

Tags: java, heroku

Every time i try to send a request to the Heroku server, it hangs until the app crashes due to the R10 error which is the server not binding to the port given by Heroku. I have no idea why this is doing this.
Here is my main class with a simple server set up for testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    port(getHerokuAssignedPort());
    get("/",(req,res) -> "Request Recived!");
}
static int getHerokuAssignedPort() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
        return Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
    }
    return 4567; //return default port if heroku-port isn't set (i.e. on localhost)
}
```

Here is my procfile:
web: java -jar attendance-bot.jar

Like I said, the program hangs until it crashes due to a port not being bound.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT"))` to get the port number.

Comment: I updated the answer. I just remembered you need to convert it to an Integer for Spark.

Comment: Yeah, thats the way I did it. It gave me the same error as the one above.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I forgot to build the jar when pushing to the heroku server.